# Book about people who physically entered the Internet using "Proxies"

Tags: story-identification

I read a book in high-school in the early 2000s (but the book may have been older than that). whose name I can't remember.

Details which I *do* remember (very hazily) are:

- People had "Proxies" which they would use to go on the Internet (or some similar thing)
- They then actually "entered" the Internet world (physically)
- There was one occasion where they were in some building and they had some sort of a contest with shotguns and they could jump really high.
- I always thought it was one of Tom Clancy's ([Net Force Explorers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Clancy%27s_Net_Force_Explorers) ones), but just can't find which one (if at all)
- The story's protagonist is a teen boy
- In one of the boy's Internet adventures, he beats up someone who bullies him in real life.

[sorry, like I said "hazy"]

The book definitely was not:

- [The Surrogates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Surrogates)
- [Proxy (Proxy, #1)](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16101023-proxy)

**What is the name of this book/book series?**
Or please confirm if it *is* the Net Force ones.

Comment: Though it could be Snow Crash by Neal Stephenson. Just started reading it, so I can't affirm most of yout details mentioned above, yet. Although @SQB mentioned it's not a match

Comment: It sounds almost like The Bohr Maker, which matches perfectly with the first two points and while I don't recall it, the third could easily have happened as well. The protagonist was definitely *not* a teen boy, however, so I'm pretty sure this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe *Web of Angels* by John M Ford? It's been quite a number of years since I read it, so my recollection is probably nearly as hazy as yours, but some elements match.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing Otherland by [Tad Williams](http://www.tadwilliams.com/).

People appear in the net as avatars of their choice, anything from models of themselves to fantastic creatures or geometric shapes. In the last part of the story, two of the main characters are hooked to the net from inside virtual reality tanks, where their bodies are completely immersed in a reactive gel.

One of the main characters is a young San Bushman called !Xabbu.

The books are massive doorstops. Lots of characters, several main story arcs that Williams merges together by the end of the series.

[Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otherland).

Comment: Only read the first part, but don't think it's a hit. Like you said, several main story arcs. "The story's protagonist is a teen boy" sound like one main character

Comment: The shotgun thing doesn't fit, and while Orlando could be the "teen boy" protagonist he never beats up any bullies IIRC. "Internet Adventures" sounds like multiple entries into the VR for separate adventures, which also doesn't fit right

Comment: Interesting, but not this one.

Comment: Shotguns and jumping high makes me think of *Outland*, but that's a completely different book, albeit one with a similar name...

Answer (score 2):

It could be [Donnerjack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donnerjack) but I would have expected Death to have made more of an impact as a character. The male teen protagonist is one of only a *very* few who can enter the virtual world(s) of the story physically most people use avatars or proxies. The only part of the story which fits with the weapons/contest is the hunting scenes where the humans and wildlife come into conflict. Check it out anyway it might be what you're after.